# Proxy connection via SSH from one terminal to another

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, proxy

I have a private proxy which can be either HTTP/SOCKS, and i am renting a Linode server that i use for web-hosting.

If I use a program like putty to SSH onto the webserver and run `who` it will display the current session and the IP of the proxy(as i used putty set with a proxy)

However, if i am on my home pc (running Kali) and I SSH onto the webserver it will display by home IP.

Basically what I'm asking is, how can i SSH from my Linux machine at home and have it do it via a proxy? I'm aware of ProxyCommand but i cant seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself with some time and effort so ill post my solution here in hopes that it will save someone some time in the future.

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X connect -x '<proxy ip>:<proxy port>' %h %p" root@<remote ip>`

This is the command that im now using to SSH onto my server through my proxy. If you wish to use the same command you might have to run:
`apt-get install netcat-openbsd` in order to run NC with the -X parameter, as the standard installed version doesn't include it.

If your proxy includes or requires authentication then you can provide the username with nc using the -P  option. This will prompt you for a password when trying to connect. Although i couldn't get this part working, it didn't seem to accept my password. I just set my proxy to accept any connection from my IP without needed to authenticate.

Hope this saves someone some time in the future.